# Whitelist Model Binding doesn't seem to work with complex properties

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders, whitelist

I have a POST action that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="userrole,credentials.emailAddress,credentials.password")]User u, string confirmPassword, bool agreeToTerms)
```

I'm using the default model binder and credentials is a property on my User object. Credentials has two fields (emailAddress & password). If I remove the Whitelist, the credentials object gets bound and everything works as expected. However, if I provide that whitelist, userrole gets bound but the email and password on the complex property does not. I checked the Form values and they care coming across as I have them listed and they match my object.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You wrote, "User object and has two fields (email & password)."  Did you mean to say that User object has a property "credentials" that has two properties "emailAddress" and "password"?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this question back in February, but if it's still valid, have you specified both your textbox's as:
`<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.credentials.emailAddress) %>`,
`<%= Html.TextBox("credentials.emailAddress") %>` or something similar?

The key point being you need to ensure your textbox's are setup with the `credentials` prefix.